# Breeze js calls metadata but doesn't make a second call to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

am writing an angular application using breeze js and asp.net odata controller. Breeze JS makes the first call to the server for metadata successfully but doesn't make the second call to actually get the data. What i can see in Chrome is

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:31549/Odata/ClientInvestments/$metadata".
```

which returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="ClientInvestment">
        <Property Name="InvestmentNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="Initials" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestorFirstName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestorLastName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestorNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="BrokerCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="UnclearedUnits" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="UnclearedMarketValue" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="BlockedUnits" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="BlockedMarketValue" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="TotalUnits" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="NavDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
        <Property Name="NavCents" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="CurrentValue" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="FundName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="FundCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="ProductName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="ProductCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="ProductType" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="EntityCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestmentType" Type="Edm.String" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="ClientTransaction">
        <Property Name="TransactionId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
        <Property Name="BrokerCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestorNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="InvestmentNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="TransactionDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
        <Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="GrossAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="AgentFee" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="VatOnFees" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="TotalAgentFees" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="NetAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="NavPrice" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="Units" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
        <Property Name="Wauc" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="ClientInvestments" EntityType="Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts.ClientInvestment" />
        <EntitySet Name="ClientTransactions" EntityType="Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts.ClientTransaction" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

then nothing

my wep api is configured like so

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("Odata", "Odata/ClientInvestments", CreateClientInvestmentEdmModel());
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("OdataCommission", "Odata/Commission", CreateCommissionEdmModel());
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("OdataAssetsUnderManagement", "Odata/AssetsUnderManagement", CreateAssetsUnderManagementEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Reports",
            routeTemplate: "api/reports/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Reports" }

        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SecondaryMarket",
            routeTemplate: "api/secondarymarket/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SecondaryMarket" }

        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Add(new CsvMediaTypeFormatter()); 
        config.Formatters.Add(new ExcelMediaTypeFormatter());

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogRequestHandler());

        config.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorFilter());

        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Default;
    }

    public static IEdmModel CreateClientInvestmentEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.Namespace = typeof(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts.ClientInvestment).Namespace;
        builder.EntitySet<Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts.ClientInvestment>(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.ClientInvestmentsServiceConstants.ClientInvestmentsQuery);
        builder.EntitySet<Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.DataContracts.ClientTransaction>(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.ClientInvestmentsService.ClientInvestmentsServiceConstants.ClientTransactionsQuery);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }

    public static IEdmModel CreateCommissionEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.Namespace = typeof(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.CommissionService.DataContracts.CommissionDetail).Namespace;
        builder.EntitySet<Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.CommissionService.DataContracts.CommissionDetail>(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.CommissionService.CommissionServiceConstants.CommissionDetailsQuery);
        builder.EntitySet<Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.CommissionService.DataContracts.CommissionSummary>(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.CommissionService.CommissionServiceConstants.CommissionSummaryQuery);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }

    public static IEdmModel CreateAssetsUnderManagementEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.Namespace = typeof(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.AssetsUnderManagementService.DataContracts.ClientAsset).Namespace;
        builder.EntitySet<Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.AssetsUnderManagementService.DataContracts.ClientAsset>(Cadiz.Services.CadizOnline.Contracts.AssetsUnderManagementService.AssetsUnderManagementServiceConstants.AssetsUnderManagementQuery);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

my javascript is configured like so

```
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({
            dataService: "OData"
        });

       var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
                    serviceName: '/Odata/ClientInvestments'
       });
       var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });
       var query = new breeze.EntityQuery('ClientInvestments');
       manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){
           var results = data;
       });
```

my odata controller looks like

```
namespace Cadiz.Web.CadizOnline.Controllers.Odata.ClientInvestments
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ClientInvestmentsController : ODataController
    {
        #region Private Members

        private readonly IClientInvestmentsService dataContext;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public ClientInvestmentsController(IClientInvestmentsService dataContext)
        {
            this.dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        [EnableQuery(MaxOrderByNodeCount = 1)]
        [ClaimsAuthorise(CadizSecurityConstants.Operations.Read, CadizSecurityConstants.Resources.Client)]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var query = dataContext.ClientInvestments;
            return Ok(query);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Virtual Methods

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                dataContext.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The EntityManager executeQuery call is asynchronous and returns a promise, so you need to call it like so:

```
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
  var results = data.results;
}
```

Comment: Ok made he change but still the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this makes a difference, but you can try to write the query like this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("ClientInvestments"); 
manager.executeQuery(query);
```

or like this:

```
new breeze.EntityQuery()  
    .from("ClientInvestments")
    .using(manager)
    .execute();
```

I'm also not sure if `OData` is the correct dataservice or if you should use `webApiOData` instead.

Comment: I made the change in javascript and I have tried with webApiOData but It still does the same thing I am using the ODataController class which inherits from ApiController is there another class I should be using instead?

Comment: `ODataController`should be fine. Have you tried to debug into executeQuery to see what happens inside Breeze?

Answer (score 0):

check your cors configuration sometimes breeze will fail silently if cors is not configured correctly